# beautiful soup extract data from script

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I get this code and I need to extract latitude and longitude from script tag.

```
<script>
 var loadPoints = '/Map/Points';
 var mapDetails = {"point":{"latitude":-34.023418,"longitude":18.331407,"title":"Sandy Bay","location":null,"subject":"P","link":"/Explore/South-Africa/Western-Cape/Sandy-Bay"},"bounds":null,"moveMarkerCallback":null,"changeBoundsCallback":null};
 requireExploreMap(loadPoints, mapDetails);
</script>
```

I can see all HTML content in soup but when I try this way:

```py
def get_textchunk(word1, word2, text):
 if not (word1 in text and word2 in text): return ''
 return text.split(word1)[-1].split(word2)[0]

lat  = get_textchunk('latitude":', ',"longitude', soup.get_text(' '))
```

it doesn't return anything.

How can I fix it?

UPDATE

This is my code

```
with open('urls.txt', 'r' ,encoding="utf-8") as inf:
    with open('data2.csv' , 'w' ,encoding="utf-8") as outf:
        outf.write('Titre,add,art,club,tel,\n')
    

    
    
    for row in inf:      
        url =  row.strip()
        response = requests.get(url)
  
     
        
        if response.ok:
            print ("ok")
           
            
           
           
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            print (soup)
            stag = soup.find("script")

            obj = json.loads(re.search(r"mapDetails\s*= \s*({.*});", str(stag)).group(1))

            lat, lon = obj["point"]["latitude"], obj["point"]["longitude"]                
            
     
           
            
        
            #Faire une pause    
            time.sleep(2)
```

The problem is BS find the first script tag and the information needed are not in the first tag.
Thanks a lot for your help

The page i try to scrap :
https://worldbeachlist.com/Explore/Australia/Victoria/Bells-Beach

Comment: Which website are you scraping ? Share code sample

Comment: please avoid using unrelated tags =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import json
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_script = """
<script>
                var loadPoints = '/Map/Points';
                var mapDetails = {"point":{"latitude":-34.023418,"longitude":18.331407,"title":"Sandy Bay","location":null,"subject":"P","link":"/Explore/South-Africa/Western-Cape/Sandy-Bay"},"bounds":null,"moveMarkerCallback":null,"changeBoundsCallback":null};
                requireExploreMap(loadPoints, mapDetails);
            </script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_script, 'html.parser').find('script').string
data = json.loads(re.search(r"mapDetails = (.+?);", soup).group(1))
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# Access the keys
print(data['point']['latitude'])
print(data['point']['longitude'])
```

Output:

```json
{
    "point": {
        "latitude": -34.023418,
        "longitude": 18.331407,
        "title": "Sandy Bay",
        "location": null,
        "subject": "P",
        "link": "/Explore/South-Africa/Western-Cape/Sandy-Bay"
    },
    "bounds": null,
    "moveMarkerCallback": null,
    "changeBoundsCallback": null
}
-34.023418
18.331407
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)/[`search`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/re.html#re.search) :

```
import re, json

stag = soup.find("script")

obj = json.loads(re.search(r"mapDetails\s*=\s*({.*});", str(stag)).group(1))

lat, lon = obj["point"]["latitude"], obj["point"]["longitude"]
```

Output :

```
print("Latitude:", lat) # Latitude: -34.023418
print("Longitude:", lon) # Longitude: 18.331407
```